# Convergence in Cantor space

Tags: general-topology

I have a sequence, in the Cantor space wrt the Cantor metric,$\{ a_{n}\} $   with the first n digits are 0 followed by 1s

Does this sequence converge?

Is it not convergent as there are lots of choices for  a possible limit?

Eg A= (1, 0, 0, 0, 0...) or B=(0, 1, 1, 1,....)

Could be limits as the distance between them and $ a_{N} $   is $2^{-N} $  which tends to 0 as N increases?

Not very keyed up on this as   cant find example in book or web of convergence

Comment: Please [use MathJax for variable names](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22029/290189) as MathJax produces nicer output.

Comment: By "Cantor metric", do you just mean the Euclidean norm restricted to the Cantor set?

Comment: No,it is defined as  0 if $x$=$y$  or  $2^{-n} $ when the n is the first place the sequences differ.

Comment: @Acccumulation Pretty sure when he says "Cantor  space" he doesn't mean the Cantor set, at least not in the form you're thinking of it, but rather the space $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ of all binary sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If d(a,b) = $2^{-n}$ with n the first place the sequences differ, then for N > 0, the first place A and $a_N$ differ is the zeroth term (assuming it's zero indexed). For B, if N > 1, the first place is the first term. So I don't see how you think the distance goes to zero; for A the distance is always 1, and for B it's always $\frac{1}{2}$. On the other hand, if we define L = (0,0,0,...), then L and $a_N$ differ on the N+1 th term, so the distance is ${2}^{-(N+1)}$, which does go to zero, so $a_n$ converges to L.

Comment: @Accumulation I was clutching at straws. it was a multiple choice question. I was given 4 sequences and it was worth 2 marks I  made $2^{-n} $ converge in $\mathbb R$ with euclidean metric, not converge with discrete metric.the last one was sequence of functions in C [0,1] given by  $f_{n}$(x)=$2^{-n}$x with respect to the metric |f-g|=max {|f(x)-g(x)|:x$\in$ C[0,1]} which I think tends to f(x)=0. so  was thinking 2 marks means 2 converge but I've  got 3

Answer (score 0):

If we have a sequence $a_n = (0,0,0,\ldots, 1, 1, 1, \ldots )$ where $a_n$ has $n$ zeroes, then this sequence converges to $(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$, as it does so 
in every coordinate: in a fixed coordinate $n$ the sequence is all $1$'s and then from the $n+1$-th term we only have $0$'s, so all tails are $0$'s in this $n$-th coordinate. So the $n$-th coordinate of the limit must also be $0$ (as projections are continuous). In the product topology convergence of a sequence is determined by its coordinate sequences. Hence my conclusion: the limit is $0$.

It is also clear if we look at the standard homeomorphism with the standard Cantor set in $[0,1]$: then $a_n$ maps to $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^{i} = 3(\frac{2}{3})^{n+1} \to 0 \,(n \to \infty)$.

Also in the Cantor metric: $d(a_n, 0) = 2^{-(n+1)} \to 0$ yielding the same conclusion again.